# How to extract key-frames closest to given frame numbers from H264 video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, keyframe, libavcodec, ffprobe

I know how to extract a set of frames as jpg files from a video using ffmpeg if you know the frame numbers (given below)

```
Extracting Frames: [40, 59, 73, 110]
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel error -i /home/pi/movie.mp4 -vf select='eq(n\,40)+eq(n\,59)+eq(n\,73)+eq(n\,110)',scale=640:-1 -vsync 0 /tmp/%04d.jpg
```

That will extract frames [40, 59, 73, 110] as files /tmp/0000.jpg, /tmp/0001.jpg, etc.

I also know how to extract all key frames for a given time interval:

```
ffmpeg -ss <start_time> -i video.mp4 -t <duration> -q:v 2 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -vsync 0 frame%03d.jpg
```

That will get all I-frames from `start_time` through `start_time+duration`.

But what I would like to do is give a list of frame numbers and have ffmpeg extract the closest key-frames to each frame-number. Is there a way to do this with ffmpeg or would I have to write my own program ontop of libavcodec to do this?

Comment: All keyframes within a given radius of the target frame, or just the nearest? Before and after?

Comment: Just the nearest, so if the key frames are at [0, 5, 10, 15, 20] and I want frames [3, 6, 12], it would return .. actually that's kind of depends on the algorithm. It could select frame 5 as closest for 3, frame 10 as closest left to 6, then 15 as closest left to 12. Ideal scenario (by sum distance to key frame over all elements) would return frames [0, 5, 10].

Answer (score 4):

If speed is the main concern, you can opt to skip non-keyframes at the demuxer stage.

```
ffmpeg -discard nokey -i video.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -vsync 0 frame%03d.jpg
```

This should provide a speed up of 20-100x.

If you need to extract all keyframes within a certain radius with the discard option, use

```
ffmpeg -discard nokey -i video.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)*(lt(abs(t-14),3)+lt(abs(t-107),3)+lt(abs(t-2113),3))" -vsync 0 frame%03d.jpg
```

Here, keyframes with a radius of 3 seconds of times t = 14s, 107s and 2113s will be selected.

You can't reference `n` with `discard` since the numbering will be wrong --> ffmpeg is only sending keyframes to the filter and `n` represents the count of the *filtered* frames. So, all variables and values are in seconds. If your video is constant frame rate, then `t` is simply `n/ fps`

Comment: I added the `-discard nokey` statement to my frame-selection query and wasn't able to produce any noticeable speedup. I used this command to extract frames 36, 56, 104, 160 and 174: `ffmpeg  -discard nokey -y -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel error -i /home/pi/test_movies/C42F90E9CDF0.0_2016-12-15T01:00:56.015236_19bb8bcf-7cf2-4e2b-9b2a-43e452865d44.mp4 -vf select='eq(n\,36)+eq(n\,56)+eq(n\,103)+eq(n\,160)+eq(n\,172)',scale=640:-1 -vsync 0 /tmp/frames%03d.jpg`. If I add the `-discard nokey` statement to the front of that there are no changes in runtime.

Comment: I just ran your command with and without nokey on a 20 min video and the results with `-benchmark` was 56sec vs 6sec.  Which version are you using? And are you running this on a phone?

Comment: I think what it might be is that I have to run this to extract, on average, 3 or 4 frames from a 12 second clip, but I have to do it from many different clips as often as possible. Might that skew the results? It's being run on a mid-range ARM-chip, yes.

Comment: If you're using ffmpeg for android, which version is it?

Comment: It's not Android it's ARM-Ubuntu 16.04, running ffmpeg 2.8.10, and I will try it with `t` instead of `n` after doing the translation and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

First we need some test data. Note you can skip to the FFmpeg commands if you
are doing this yourself; this is just how I came about the final commands:

```sh
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries frame=pict_type -of flat \
'Breaking Bad 5x4 Fifty-One.mp4' > pict_type.txt
```

Now let us find the largest window:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS = "[.\42]"
}
$5 != "I" {
  pa++
}
$5 == "I" {
  qu = pa > qu ? pa : qu
  pa = 1
}
END {
  print qu
}
```

Running this yields 240, which means the radius is 120. If our target frame is
1000:

```sh
ffmpeg -i 'Breaking Bad 5x4 Fifty-One.mp4' \
-vf "select='eq(pict_type,I)*lt(abs(n-1000),120)'" -frames 1 outfile.jpg
```

If our targets frames are 1000 and 2000:

```sh
ffmpeg -i 'Breaking Bad 5x4 Fifty-One.mp4' \
-vf "select='eq(pict_type,I)*(lt(abs(n-1000),120)+lt(abs(n-2000),120))'" \
-frames 2 -vsync 0 %d.jpg
```

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation

Comment: I was able to try your suggestions and got some surprising results. Here are two examples and their outputs.

`time ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -nostats -loglevel error -i movie.mp4 -vf "select='eq(pict_type,I)*(lt(abs(n-36),120)+lt(abs(n-56),120)+lt(abs(n-103),120)+lt(abs(n-160),120)+lt(abs(n-172),120))',scale=640:-2" -frames 5 -vsync 0 /tmp/frames%03d.jpg`


real 0m0.761s
user 0m2.232s
sys 0m0.052s

Comment: compared to the way listed in the OP without the `lt(abs` statements:


real 0m0.749s
user 0m2.244s
sys 0m0.056s

Comment: @JohnAllard that difference is negligible

Comment: I guess that was my point, I figured that only getting key-frames would be a noticeable speed-up over the naive 'extract these frames with no though of their relation to key-frames' method.